# Error while adding the Crosswalk WebView plugin to an Android project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, plugman

I have a Cordova project where I have added the iOS and Android platform. I am trying to install the Crosswalk WebView plugin to the Android platform only but I get following error. For the sake of clarity I have added the versions of the CLI tools I am using and the steps I have performed below. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

## software versions

cordova -v

> 6.1.1

plugman -v

> 1.3.0

## create cordova project

cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld;cd hello

> Creating a new cordova project.

## add platforms

cordova platform add ios --save

> Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
>   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
>   --save flag or autosave detected
>   Saving ios@~4.1.1 into config.xml file ...

cordova platform add android --save

> Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
>       Path: platforms/android
>       Package: com.example.hello
>       Name: HelloWorld
>       Activity: MainActivity
>       Android target: android-23
>   Android project created with cordova-android@5.1.1

## check if platforms were installed successfully

cordova platform ls

> Installed platforms:
>     android 5.1.1
>     ios 4.1.1

## add Crosswalk WebView only to android project

plugman install --platform android --plugin https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git --project .

> Fetching plugin "https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git" via git clone
>   Repository "https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git" checked out to git ref "master".
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" for android
>   **cordova-android version not detected (lacks script "/Users/dga/Desktop/hello/cordova/version**" ), continuing.
>    Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-android is being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-android@5.0.0 or newer.
>   **Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview':CordovaError: The provided path "/Users/dga/Desktop/hello" is not an Android project**.
>       at new android_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/android_parser.js:35:15)
>       at new PlatformApiPoly (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/PlatformApiPoly.js:62:20)
>       at Object.getPlatformApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:68:23)
>       at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:610:29)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:407:28
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:0wned:hello

Comment: Did you follow the steps here:https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html